# Timeout using cryptsetup passdev in crypttab

Tags: usb, debian, cryptography

firsty I know it is not very safety storing the key on a stick but I am lazy and let's say I run around with a implanted usb-drive ;-)

The scenario is the following.
Disks:

```
sda                                          8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1                                       8:1    0   487M  0 part  /boot
├─sda2                                       8:2    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5                                       8:5    0   931G  0 part
  └─sda5_crypt                             254:1    0   931G  0 crypt
    ├─marvserv--vg-root                    254:2    0 278.3G  0 lvm   /
    └─marvserv--vg-swap_1                  254:3    0   976M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    
sdd                                          8:48   0   3.6T  0 disk
└─marvserver_encrypt-marvserv_encrypt_home 254:0    0   3.6T  0 lvm
  └─encrypt_home                           254:4    0   3.6T  0 crypt /mnt/encrypt_home
```

During the boot both devices should get via passdev or another keyscript passed the key which is stored in a keyfile on a usb-drive. Somehow passdev timeout or the keyscript didn't get the keyfile interpreted correctly.

I've created for both of them a keyfile using dd and then add the key accordingly to the device,sda5_crypt with b2552556-5eb6-11ed-9ecf-6b30b12a33e2.lek and b2552556-5eb6-11ed-9ecf-6b30b12a33e2.lek for encrypt_home. Both of the keys are working, I've double checked this with a live-system. The second one(not root...) can be encrypted during boot using the keyfile when the usb-drive is mount and I entered the absolut path in crypttab but for the other one it is not working(cryptsetup: WARNING: Skipping root target sda5_crypt: uses a key file).
Dirty solution modifiy some code at crytsetup to avoid the Warning but this has to be done everytime cryptsetup get's updated...

Proper solution using a keyscript like passdev (https://cryptsetup-team.pages.debian.net/cryptsetup/README.initramfs.html#the-passdev-keyscript)
Example:

```
cryptroot /dev/sda2 /dev/disk/by-label/myusbkey:/keys/root.key discard,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=256,hash=sha1,keyscript=passdev
```

And here is my entry at the crypttab for the second vg:

```
encrypt_home UUID=7d9258cd-a71b-449c-bac8-f40a1a84d9f3 /dev/disk/by-uuid/E622-586F:b2552556-5eb6-11ed-9ecf-6b30b12a33e2.lek luks,discard,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/passdev
```

I've also tried like changes like /dev/disk/by-uuid/E622-586F:/b2552556-5eb6-11ed-9ecf-6b30b12a33e2.lek (adding slash) /dev/disk/by-uuid/E622-586F:/b2552556-5eb6-11ed-9ecf-6b30b12a33e2 (removing lek) and also another keyscript(https://tqdev.com/2022-luks-with-usb-unlock)

Both without success so it is eather passdev time out or using the script(luksunlockusb) path is not absolute in crypttab which is referring to the third entry(b2552556-5eb6-11ed-9ecf-6b30b12a33e2) at crypttab:

```
encrypt_home UUID=7d9258cd-a71b-449c-bac8-f40a1a84d9f3 b2552556-5eb6-11ed-9ecf-6b30b12a33e2 luks,discard,keyscript=/bin/luksunlockusb
```

These four modules I've added to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules as well:

```
vfat
nls_cp437
nls_ascii
usb_storage
```

and after every change at crypttab I run update-initramfs -u

The usb-drive is formatted and the keys transfered using this script:
https://github.com/mevdschee/bitlocker-luks-tools/blob/main/create_usb.sh

The keys are stored at the root folder only with the read-flag and root as owner but as mentioned before if I've mounted the usb-stick at boot via fstab and enter the absolut path at crypttab it is working so far the second disk.

Is there any module I need to add or is it a different syntax and here the debian-version I am using:
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye

//Update:
Using the following line in crypttab:

```
encrypt_home UUID=7d9258cd-a71b-449c-bac8-f40a1a84d9f3 /dev/disk/by-uuid/E622-586F:b2552556-5eb6-11ed-9ecf-6b30b12a33e2.lek luks,discard,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/passdev
```

Checking if it is working using:

```
cryptdisks_start encrypt_home
```

Is also working. Debian inform

```
EXT4-fs (sde1): VFS:Can't find ext4 filesystem
```

But the fstype of the usb-stick is vfat and fsver is FAT16 and with some googeling I've found something like if you are not specify the type when executing mount it just automatically tries. Nevertheless at some point he got the right filessystem and unlocks the crypted lvm.
So with this infomation is feels like a module is missing at boottime which mounts the usb-stick correctly.

Comment: I'm the author on TQdev.com, it seems you are using an encrypt home partition and not an encryted root partition (as in the article), or am I wrong? Encrypted root requires unlocking at boot time, while encrypted home partitions can be unlocked at any time.

Comment: Hey mevdschee, you mentioned the second volumegroup, for this one everything is working if I mount the usb via fstab and then encrypt the lvm via crypttab. But for the other one which contains the root partition it is not possible because it is root. So one time it is LVM on LUKS(encrypt_home) and the other one is LUKS on LVM(sda5_crypt). https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#LVM_on_LUKS

Comment: Hey muxLeet, you need to set the label 'myusbkey' on the fat partition for the USB drive in order for Debian 11 to boot using 'passdev' as the keyscript (as you specified that label). Also the passdev timeout variable is not (yet/properly) implemented (in Debian 11). I tested this in a VM and passdev works, but it did cause a start job to hang for 1min30 on the USB drive (probably doesn't unmount).

Comment: Thanks for testing that out.What do you mean by label? I am using this line in cryptsetup:
encrypt_home UUID=7d9258cd-a71b-449c-bac8-f40a1a84d9f3 /dev/disk/by-uuid/E622-586F:b2552556-5eb6-11ed-9ecf-6b30b12a33e2.lek luks,discard,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/passdev

I assume u mean this by label /dev/disk/by-uuid/E622-586F:b2552556-5eb6-11ed-9ecf-6b30b12a33e2.lek 
I cannot mount the usb and use /mnt... as label because when you run initramfs he throws an error that the key is on that path. Passdev or custom keyscripts should be used.

Comment: Sorry.. confused multiple different posts/issues.. I thought you were loading the usb device by label, but you load it by uuid. I see no problem with your setup. You may use a '/' after the ':' to indicate the file is at the root. Also you may specify 'passdev' instead of the fullpath and you may identify by label instead of uuid, allowing another USB drive to be used.

Comment: muxLeet FYI, I haven't tested encrypted home, only encrypted root and that seems to work.